# At an impasse using OpenCV

Tags: ros, opencv, cv-bridge, opencv3, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have this snippet of code that was copied from one of the tutorials on cv_bridge:

```
try
{
  ROS_INFO("Trying to convert");
  cv_ptr = toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BAYER_BGGR8);
  ROS_INFO("Converted");
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
  ROS_INFO("Not Converted");

  ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
  return;
}
```

And when I run it using a topic published by my camera I run into this error:

```
[ INFO] [1435952032.594731416]: Trying to convert
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unknown/unsupported array type) in type, file /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-opencv3-3.0.0-0trusty-20150607-1913/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1837
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-opencv3-3.0.0-0trusty-20150607-1913/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1837: error: (-213) Unknown/unsupported array type in function type

Aborted (core dumped)
```

(The ROS_INFO's are there to show steps and when there program breaks)

Now I know the error is in that line so I tried a few other things to get it to work. When I change the encoding type to something else, in this case bayer_grbg8, I get this error:

```
 [ INFO] [1435952475.576702858]: Step2
[ INFO] [1435952475.576715724]: Trying to convert
[ INFO] [1435952475.576814017]: Not Converted
[ERROR] [1435952475.576841782]: cv_bridge exception: Unsupported conversion from [bayer_bggr8] to [bayer_grbg8]
```

What are some possible solutions? I don't know how to change the encoding of the camera (Point Grey Blackfly3)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212860/at-an-impasse-using-opencv/) by [chilypepper](https://answers.ros.org/users/23050/chilypepper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It caused by conflict between opencv2 and opencv2. You should find the following script in your package CMakeFile.txt:

find_package(OpenCV  REQUIRED)

Replace it with

find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)

I worked whole day to find the solution

---

Originally posted by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) with karma: 73 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1